# Should I adjust for inflation in a staggereded DiD with money as outcome and if so, how?

Tags: regression, econometrics, panel-data, fixed-effects-model, difference-in-difference

This question is currently making my head spin, and I haven't been able to find a discussion on it so far:

Suppose I am interested in the effect of an intervention, such as a healthcare reform, on a monetary outcome, for example, healthcare expenditure in Euros. My pre-period is 2014, and my post-period is 2016.

In a difference-in-differences setting, I would assume that the general increase in healthcare expenditure should be accounted for by the time fixed effect, and that the difference-in-differences estimate provides the treatment effect. But how much is that "additional" money worth? Based on my understanding, it pertains to 2016 Euros because this is the time when we are measuring the effect.

While in a two-period scenario, this is mostly a matter of interpretation, I am pondering whether one should give more thought to it in a multi-period scenario. Suppose the healthcare reform was implemented in a phased rollout, and I want to estimate [group-time average treatment effects, as suggested by Callaway & Sant'Anna](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0304407620303948). Suppose I calculate a combined treatment effect for all groups relative to their own treatment time: Am I mixing apples and oranges because some of the treatment effects were measured in terms of 2016 Euros, while others were measured in 2022 Euros?

If my concern is valid, would it be sufficient to adjust for inflation and express all costs in terms of, for example, 2014 Euros before applying the difference-in-differences estimator?